# Calculating percentage of string occurrence in column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have search for this question but haven't got the help I needed. 
Let's say I have this data.frame:

```
df<-data.frame(
  "id"= 1:10, 
  "fruit"=c("apple", "banana", "orange", "apple","apple", "banana", 
            "orange","apple", "banana", "orange"),
  "bowl"=c("red", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green",
            "green", "green","red","red")
             )
```

I want to create faceted pie charts and therefore I want to know the percentage of each fruit per bowl. If this would've been numeric values I would've found lot's of help, but I don't seem to be able to use it since it's string. 
I have tried variations of:

```
df %>% group_by(bowl) %>% mutate(varfruit=count(fruit))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. Not the most efficient way, but it helps to run the code line by line to see what's going on.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(bowl) %>% 
  mutate(bowl_size = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(bowl, fruit) %>% 
  mutate(
    fruit_size = n(), 
    fruit_pct = fruit_size / bowl_size
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(bowl)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .N, .(fruit, bowl)][, perc := N/sum(N), .(bowl)][]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, we can `count` each `fruit` for every `bowl` and to get ratio divide it by total number of `fruits`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(bowl) %>%
  count(fruit) %>%
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n)) %>%
  select(-n)

#  bowl  fruit   perc
#  <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
#1 green apple  0.429
#2 green banana 0.286
#3 green orange 0.286
#4 red   apple  0.333
#5 red   banana 0.333
#6 red   orange 0.333
```

---

A base R option using `prop.table`

```
prop.table(with(df, table(bowl, fruit)), 1)

#     fruit
#bowl        apple    banana    orange
#  green 0.4285714 0.2857143 0.2857143
#  red   0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

If you want to maintain the long structure of the data we can convert it into dataframe by

```
data.frame(prop.table(with(df, table(bowl, fruit)), 1))
```

Comment: Thank you! Helped me solve my issue. I am obviously a beginner :)